# Sf/Twig - count number of property with same value

Tags: symfony, twig

I just want to display on a twig view the number of a property with a value defined like

```
 <div class="list-group">
          {% for ticket in tickets %}
            {% if ticket.statut == 'En attente' %}
                {{ loop.index }}
                {{ ticket.statut }}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start"><a href="{{ path('ticket', {id:ticket.id}) }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i> {{ ticket.getNomProduit }}</div></a>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
```

but i got the right number(2) but i would only display the number of this specific ticket with value "En attente"

[image]

Comment: Hi, The image you sent is your result or your expectation ?
WHat is your problem exactly because it is not clear.

Comment: Hi, its the result yes, but i just want to display "2 en attente". thats all. I dunno if i need to use a specific filter ou use a variable

Comment: So you want to show the total of ticket with status "En attente". Without the div you show in the code ?

Comment: the total and below the list of specific ticket

Comment: Please clarify your question by editing it. What do you mean by "count"?

Comment: count, the total of properties which has the string value "en attente"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to implement such a thing, I would do it somewhere in the PHP controller, something like this:

```php
// In the controller:

$ticketsEnAttente = array_filter($tickets,
    function($ticket) {
        return $ticket['statut'] === 'En attente';
    }
);

return $this->render('my_template.html.twig', [
    'tickets_en_attente' => $ticketsEnAttente,
]);
```

Then it is trivial to show the count and the different tickets in Twig, something like:

```
<div>
    {{ tickets_en_attente | length }} tickets en attente:
</div>
{% for ticket in tickets_en_attente %}
    {{ loop.index }}
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
        <a href="{{ path('ticket', {id:ticket.id}) }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
            <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i>
            {{ ticket.getNomProduit }}
        </div>
    </a>  {# NOTE: there is an html error in your code, </div> and </a> are inverted #}
{% endfor %}
```

The only difference here is that the loop index will not be the same as the original code you gave, because it takes only into account the filtered list.

In a general way, it is a good idea to put as few as possible complex computations in the twig templates. Controllers and services are a better place for it.

#### EDIT

To answer to your comment, if there are several statuses, you can create a variable which groups tickets by their status:

```
// In your controller:

// Mock data:
$tickets = [
    [ 'id' => 1, 'statut' => 'Fermé' ],
    [ 'id' => 2, 'statut' => 'En attente' ],
    [ 'id' => 3, 'statut' => 'Ouvert' ],
    [ 'id' => 4, 'statut' => 'En attente' ],
];

// Group tickets by status:
$ticketsByStatus = [];
foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    $ticketsByStatus[$ticket['statut']][] = $ticket;
}

// This is equivalent to writing this by hand:
$ticketsByStatus = [
    'Fermé' => [
        [ 'id' => 1, 'statut' => 'Fermé' ],
    ],
    'En attente' => [
        [ 'id' => 2, 'statut' => 'En attente' ],
        [ 'id' => 4, 'statut' => 'En attente' ],
    ],
    'Ouvert' => [
        [ 'id' => 3, 'statut' => 'Ouvert' ],
    ],
];

return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
    'tickets_by_status' => $ticketsByStatus,
]);
```

Then you can iterate over each status in the template (or access them manually if you prefer), something like this:

```
{% for status in tickets_by_status|keys %}
    <h4>{{ status }}:</h4>
    <ul>
        {% for ticket in tickets_by_status[status] %}
            <li>
                {{ ticket.id }}
                {#   {{ ticket.getNomProduit }}   #}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Up to you to make this fit to your own needs.

Comment: Indeed, better way to implement in the controller. Thank you!

Comment: And could i use many arguments into the function, like if i would many filters "En attente","Ouvert",..  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="list-group">
         {% set count = 0 %}
          {% for ticket in tickets %}
            {% if ticket.statut == 'En attente' %}
                {{ loop.index }}
                {{ ticket.statut }}
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-start"><a href="{{ path('ticket', {id:ticket.id}) }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active"><i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i> {{ ticket.getNomProduit }}</div></a>
               {% set count = count + 1 %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {{ count }} Total File En attente
</div>
```

Comment: Its the same result, either we set a count variable or loop variable.

Comment: NO it is not !! Because loop.index will give you the number of loop it is doing no matter if it goes through your `if`. So if you ticket status will be "Terminé" between 2 tickets then you will have 1 En attente, 3 En attente. because the second one will be another statut. As the count will trully show the number of ticket !